# Отображение трека из файла GPX

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Необходимо на карту наносить трек пути из файла GPX, как сделано в [примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoxml_display).

Проблема в том, что в примере файл GPX загружается методом **.load('файл GPX')**, но непонятно как загрузить файл через input **type="file"** и вывести общий километраж по всему пути.

Answer (score 1):

Метод .load() требует, чтобы файл был доступен через интернет. То есть в инпуте надо указывать либо ссылку на доступный сетевой ресурс, либо сначала загружать файл куда-то к себе на сервер, а потом в load скармливать уже ссылку на сетевое размещение.

Comment: Если файл лежит в корневой папке сайта, то он все равно не обрабатывается.

Comment: файл должен быть сам по себе доступен по прямому урлу из интернета, это связано с препроцессингом файла этим методом - он не может брать его локально.

Comment: Файл лежит на FTP, в корне, где и index.html, но все равно не обрабатывается.

Comment: Вы пробовали указать абсолютный url? Если собрать пример на jsfiddle и  там указать полный путь до вашего файла, он загрузится? Просто по прямой ссылке файл открывается из интернета?

Comment: Указывал относительный url - не работало, с абсолютным вроде работает: https://jsfiddle.net/Roman69/y1bpop1h/ Остался вопрос - как отобразить километраж по проложенному пути и почему-то не работает центрирование карты myMap.setBounds

Comment: лучше по каждой проблема задавать отдельный вопрос, чтобы не получилась каша из ответов. Центрирование надо сделать так: myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());

Comment: myMap.setBounds не подходит, так как на карте много различных объектов, а центрировать надо именно на треке

Comment: Тогда так myMap.setBounds(res.geoObjects.getBounds()); Повторюсь, создавайте отдельный вопрос на каждую проблему с полной информацией, иначе получается гадание на кофейной гуще, а что же вам там надо сделать

Comment: Спасибо, так работает